# Connection refused from java(fx) HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, c++, javafx, httpurlconnection

After catching up with Java and Windows 7 updates a few days ago some net code stopped working from JavaFX program(connection is refused). Url works well from Chrome browser. Going from 8u91 back to 8u71 does not fix the problem.

The server code is our C++ (Boost) code. Netstat gives expected results as far as listening on socekts is concerned.

I.e. localhost or local IP addr do not work. Connecting to the same server in or data centre works well.

I made no changes at the net configuration at the time code stopped working.

Code (have too many options below for experimentation, but no mater how I combine them it will not work. Firewalls are down, port doesn't matter):

```
    HttpURLConnection urlc = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlS);
        urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(0);
        urlc.setReadTimeout(0);
        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
        urlc.setDoInput(true);
        urlc.setUseCaches(false);
        //urlc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0a2) Gecko/20110613 Firefox/6.0a2");
        InputStream stream = urlc.getInputStream();
```

...

Comment: Works over IPv6, although it looks like server is listening on both IP stacks. Might be our C++ problem.

Can Java be "pushed" to work dual-stack for "localhost" (now I have http://[::]/Login.qsx?Username....)

Comment: Seeing that this is a `HttpURLConnection` it is not related to JavaFX. Have you tried debugging with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`? Beware that this can add some serious overhead and slow down the application considerably.

Comment: I removed the old code and replaced it with the RESTFul interface.
Works fine now.